# Weird internet connection errors. Many HTTP requests just time out on a direct connection but work fine over a VPN connection

Tags: networking

I currently have a FTTH (fiber-to-the-home) connection. It is a symmetric 600 Mbps connection.

- Speed is exactly what I am paying for.
- Jitter is about 1.5 ms.
- No packet loss. (Apparently from many synthetic tests)
- Very low latency. As expected in a Fiber optic connection.

The problem is that I am experiencing constant HTTP request errors. For instance, while playing GTA, when purchasing items in a store, the game performs one petition to the server for each bought item. If I buy 20 items, 20 requests are made, if I do so, **2 or 3 requests out of 20 simply time-out as if the server was not responding.**

I've been able to observe that this behavior occurs not only while playing GTA, but also in my other computers. I work with a Mac as a software developer, and many times during the day I experience the same issue when making requests to my company servers.

In order to be sure that something is going on with my connection. **I installed a (paid) VPN in both the PC and the Mac**. I've been using such VPN for a week now, and my experience is way way better than before. GTA just works, and during the day while working **everything works seamlessly as I expect.**

So my question is. At this point, I am not sure if the issue is related with my equipment (I have made some changes in the "default" installation. It was working for 2+ years without issues) or with the ISP. **I would like to have a set of tests or a program that can help me to monitor the connection for this specific problem.** (A problem that I have not been able to "name" in order to find answers online).

Finally, my main fear is that the issue is related to the ISP. If that is the case, how in the world I will be able to explain this to a support agent?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Additional info you might ask:

- Both machines (Win and Mac) are connected via Gigabit ethernet to a TP-LINK Archer C1200. I have several other devices (phones, AppleTV, tablet, consoles) connected wirelessly or via ethernet. As I don't use those machines for long periods of time (unlike the computers) I've not been able to see the issues there.
- The TP-LINK is connected to a "Sagemcom Fast 5655v2" (provided by the ISP) the Fiber Optic cable is connected to this device. It is configured as "bridge" so the routing happens in the TP-LINK.
- This setup has been working perfectly for 2 or 3 years now, I started experiencing these weird issues about a month ago.

Comment: This could be caused by an incorrect MTU value in your router or VPN settings. The classic symptom is that [short, simple](http://www.neverssl.com/) web pages load fine but long pages sometimes fail. Search for something like, "how to find the correct mtu value", but note that `ping` parameters are different on different platforms.

Comment: Seconding suggestion by @bitinerant. I had the exact same issue when an upstream ISP changed their max MTU without telling us. Everything encapsulated by our VPN (which happened to use a fairly low MTU) worked fine, while anything that involved a reasonable amount of data croaked outside of the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue on your routers firmware and its ability to track enough concurrent sessions.  (If your ISP is doing CGN that could explain it)

You might want to try flashing dd-wrt on the router.